# How to create Table per type inheritance in Entity Framework Core 2.0 code first?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Following code generates only single table "CertificateEvent".

**How do I achieve TPT inheritance in EF Core 2.0?**

```
public abstract class CertificateEvent {
   public int CertificateEventId { get; set; }
}

public class Assignment : CertificateEvent {...}
public class Assessment : CertificateEvent {...}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Assessment> AssessorAssessments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Assignment> AssessorAssignments { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<CertificateEvent>().ToTable(nameof(CertificateEvent));
        modelBuilder.Entity<Assessment>().ToTable(nameof(Assessment));
        modelBuilder.Entity<Assignment>().ToTable(nameof(Assignment));
    }
}

class MyDesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>
{
    public MyDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
        builder.UseSqlServer("Server=(local);Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
        return new MyDbContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

I've also tried `dotnet ef migrations add Inheritance`, but it did not created TPT inheritance in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TPT is not in EF Core (yet).  See

> The feeling from our team is that TPT is generally an anti-pattern and
>   results in significant performance issues later on. While enabling it
>   may make some folks "happier" to start with it ultimately just leads
>   to issues. We are willing to consider it though, so we're leaving this
>   open and will consider it based on the feedback we get.

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/2266

Comment: In case CertificateEvent was concrete class, would it be possible to write TPC?

Comment: No.  Currently TPH only is supported, and for code-first scenarios it is also recommended.  TPH was implemented first because it's the best strategy for most new applications.

Comment: But you can map the concrete subtypes completely separately by excluding the base class from the DbContext.  You will get two tables, Assesment, and Assignment with no relationship between them.

Comment: The only problem I have is that I will have too many inherited classes and I don't want to end up with table with hundred columns .  I will need to select all CertificateEvents, so separate tables without relationship is not possible.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Our team is converting a WPF app to asp.net core mvc. The WPF app uses TPT. In order to get things done quickly we are using the composition provided when the entity classes are generated. I just updated the entity classes to mirror legacies'. I'm about to try to generate a new db schema via new entity classes thus giving us a TPH structure. The ? I'm currently working on(in my head) is what are the advantages of composition over inheritance and vice/versa in this situation. I'll probably figure it out later but dropped that ? here in case you could answer it easily.

Comment: If I understand you, you are creating an EF Core model that maps to the existing tables used in EF6 TPT.  This will result in a model that uses composition instead of inheritance.  You will loose some of the coding convenience that the inheritance model provided.  Eg Customer.Person.Name instead of Customer.Name, etc.

Comment: Just wanted to thank you guys, you actually helped me with understanding EF core better. What approach would you suggest, at the end?
Having a huge table with a lot of nullables just feels bad, and is having TPT worh the trade off (using composition instead of inheritance) in your opinion? Is TPT such a bad practice (vs. TPH) in the first place?

Comment: IMO if your TPH approaches "huge with a lot of nullables" double check that you really should be using Inheritence.  EG inheriting all Entities from an EntityBase and storing in a single TPH table is definitely a bad practice.  But if you worries about null columns is performance-related, it _still_ performs much better than TPT.

Comment: If entity framework core doesnt not support TPT, we are going to use eXpress Persistent Objects (XPO). Is there any release date or plan to implement TPT?

Comment: Here's the issue. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/2266 Not soon.  But you will be able to use EF6 on .NET Core 3.

Comment: Can we use EF6 Features in Linux Container? or just EF6 in Windows Container?

Comment: .Net Core 3 runs on Windows and Linux.